# Calculating the time for a 31$\rm ^\circ F$ ice cube to melt?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, estimation, ice

Is there a way to calculate how long it would take for an ice cube to melt in relation to it being surrounded by different levels of insulation (Is R-value the best way to measure insulation for this)? And also the temperature outside that insulation? Assuming no wind or other factors.

Basically how long can the ice cube remain an ice cube practically speaking with increased insulation? I guess this is also a thought experiment on diminishing returns of an ever increasing thermos thickness.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A 31°F ice cube will remain an ice cube forever if no heat is added. You would need to specify a temperature of the surrounding air or insulation, and how that temperature is maintained (heat flux).   It's quite a complicated question that has no simple answer. Your best bet is searching for test data on that scenario, or running tests yourself.

Comment: @RC_23 Assuming constant 62f outside the insulation with zero wind or other factors. I tried to give scenarios but it asked me to limit the question. OT outside temp IN inside temp R insulation level